# Update a column in mysql based on where statement with subselects

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this pseudo SQL code for what I want to achieve:

```
UPDATE orders o
SET o.datePaid = null

WHERE
    (
        SELECT SUM(amount)
        FROM transactions t
        WHERE t.orderId = o.id
        AND t.status = 'success'
        AND t.type = 'refund'
    )
    >=
    (
        SELECT SUM(amount)
        FROM transactions t
        WHERE t.orderId = o.id
        AND t.status = 'success'
        AND t.type IN ('purchase', 'capture')
    )
```

How would I do this in SQL?

Comment: Your code would probably work as it is, did you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach is interesting.  Here is a more concise method:

```
UPDATE orders o
    SET o.datePaid = null
WHERE (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN t.type = 'refund' THEN amount
                       WHEN t.type IN ('purchase', 'capture') THEN -amount
                  END)
       FROM transactions t
       WHERE t.orderId = o.id AND
             t.status = 'success'
      ) > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code would probably work just as it is. Give it a try.

You could also optimize the query to avoid the need for two subqueries by using a `JOIN` and conditional aggregation in a single subquery:

```
UPDATE orders o
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT orderId
    FROM transactions
    WHERE 
        status = 'success' 
        AND type IN ('success', 'purchase', 'capture')  -- this condition might be superfuous
    GROUP BY o.id       
    HAVING
        SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'success' THEN amount ELSE 0 END)
            >= SUM(CASE WHEN type IN ('purchase', 'capture') THEN amount ELSE 0 END)
) t ON t.orderId = o.id
SET o.datePaid = null
```

Note: `WHERE` condition `AND type IN ('success', 'purchase', 'capture')` is superfluous if that list of 3 values represents all the possible values.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I could only choose one!

Answer (score 1):

Your query works fine as is. However it can be more optimally written using MySQL multi-table `UPDATE` syntax:

```
UPDATE orders o
LEFT JOIN (SELECT orderId,
              COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'refund' THEN amount END), 0) AS refunds,
              COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN type IN ('purchase', 'capture') THEN amount END), 0) AS pc
           FROM transactions
           WHERE status = 'success'
           GROUP BY orderId) t ON t.orderId = o.id
SET o.datePaid = NULL
WHERE t.refunds > t.pc
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=07e9ad82eaa79b7efae032db7f9a36a5) (includes your query working as well)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I could only choose one!